# Break facebook like button text line "One like. Sign Up to see what your friends like

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

How can Break facebook like button text line

"One like. Sign Up to see what your friends like."

like

"One like. Sign Up to (line break)
see what your friends like."

i have tried to reduce the width but it's not working.

here is the code:

```
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php' + location.pathname + '" layout="standard" show_faces="" width="250" action="like" font="lucida grande" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

or add it to the link itself:

```
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php' + location.pathname + '" layout="standard" style="white-space:nowrap;" show_faces="" width="250" action="like" font="lucida grande" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```